# CodeIgniter, multiple possible segments in one route

Tags: codeigniter, routes

Ok, so maybe that title is a bit confusing. What I'd like to do is trap any info, if any after the first URI segement if that segment is something specific and forward that on to another controller. Here's my routes file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['testroute'] = "main";
```

So, what this does right now is, if I got to mydomain.com/testroute it shows me the default page, which it should. However, what I'd like is if I go to mydomain.com/testroute/testmethod/ where testmethod is a method in the main controller I'd like it to forward that as well. So basically I'd like it to route to the main controller regardless of if there are more segments after the testroute, but if there are they should get passed as method calls of the main controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply catch the parameter given and pass it to the controller e.g. like this:

```
$route['testroute/(:any)'] = "main/$1";
```

`(:any)` actually catches any type of string. There are other selectors, as well. More on this topic can be found [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).

Edit (answer to your comment):

If you want a general route to the index() method of your main controller, just add both routes:

```
$route['testroute'] = "main";
$route['testroute/(:any)'] = "main/$1";
```

Comment: yeah. I tried that. The problem is I get a 404 if i just go to testroute/ without any segments afterward. Is there a way to make it resolve to the index of main if there are no more segments without having to declare a seperate route?

Comment: See above, I edited the answer. Plus, I really suggest taking a look at the article in the CI manual, there are plenty ways to make routings (with regular expressions and other nice stuff)

Comment: response to edit: yeah, i figured that's what i'd have to do, I just wanted to try to keep it to one route for simplicity's sake if possible.

Comment: @LoneWolfPR. Do you want to redirect to the index method all the time?
Try $route['testroute/(:any)'] = "main/index/$1";
The $1 will be the first parameter to the index method

Comment: @Ben I guess what he wants is if a parameter is given after testroute, it should route to the specific action in the controller, otherwise (i.e. no parameter given) it should call the `index()` action.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

Uh, what? That's how CodeIgniter's controllers work already. Show us some code? What isn't working about it?

Have you configured URL rewriting in your .htaccess file so you don't need the `/index.php/testroute` in the URL?

Open .htaccess, and try this code if you haven't already rewritten this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

If you haven't configured rewriting then it won't work without that^, but you can access like `mydomain.com/path/to/ci/index.php/testroute/testmethod`

Comment: @Ben Refresh, please. See I edited the answer to include more info to try.

Comment: @Ben: Do you know how CI works? It does exactly as OP asked by default without any modification other than adding the .htaccess rewrite rules. What do you think OP is asking for then?

Comment: He's asking what @Martin is trying to answer

Comment: this site will act as normal most of the time (routing the first segment to a controller of the same name as the segment). However I have a few possibilities where the first segment will essentially be like a subsite and will need to be routed back to the main controller passing all furter segments to that. My preference had been to use subdomains for each subsite, but my client wants it to be mydomain.com/site1, mydomain.com/site2, etc. So the site1, site2, etc. calls need to route back to the main controller where it will be a different skin and some different content based on the subsite.

Comment: @LoneWolfPR: So basically just an extra segment in between the normal things?

Comment: yeah, but it won't always be there. Think of it this way. I go to mydomain.com/ and it works like normal. I go to mydomain.com/site1 I get the same structure as mydomain.com but with a different skin and dynamic content. So site1 needs access to all the same methods so I wanted to tie it to the same controller.

So mydomain.com/site1/somecontroller would call the same controller as mydomain.com/somecontroller. I just have code catching the extra segment and loading the proper skin and data for that subsite.

Comment: Ah, okay, makes sense. I think @Ben's downvote isn't entirely necessary, since the initial question was unclear about what was going on so my answer doesn't really make sense now.

Comment: I upped it to counteract the - since you stuck around to figure out what I was talking about.